# Iptables forwarding with single interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, routing

Is it possible to use `Iptables` to forward all traffic going to certain network to given ip address?

I have `Ubuntu server` to act as router in network `192.168.1.0/24`.
Its `IP` is `192.168.1.254`. (This "router" has only single networking interface `eth0`.)

Clients on the `192.168.1.0/24` network have this static route set up:

```
Network      Mask           Gateway
172.16.1.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.1.254
```

With this the clients send traffic going to `172.16.1.0` to my router.

With router I want to redirect traffic going to `172.16.1.0` to ip `192.168.2.254`.

I don't want address translation, device on `192.168.2.254` should see the traffic coming from client, not from the router on `192.168.1.254`.

(This may seem quite complecated and this because I have no control over devices between these networks. That is why I created new router inside my network instead of adding new route to the router that connects these networks.)

I have enabled ip forwarding from `sysctl.conf`.

I have tried this `Iptables` configuration:

Get packages that need routing:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             172.16.1.0/24      to:192.168.2.254
```

Forward these packages to target:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.2.254
```

But this does not apperar to be doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by getting second network interface to my router device. I configured second interface to connect the other other network.

Then I just created new static route to my virtual network using `ip route add` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send traffic from a source to a destination you need to use `static routes` instead `iptables`. `Iptables` let you accept or deny any traffic going trough your machine, but it will no redirect any data.

For your purpose, you can try with the following route in your Ubuntu Server Router `192.168.1.254`:

```
ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.254
```

This shouldn't make any NAT on the routed packets.

Comment: The command gives me this error: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`. I wonder if this is because the server is not in same network as the target.